# Not a class, namespace, or enumeration after making a template class?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to templatize a few classes (LinkedListNode and LinkedList), such that

```
template <class T>
class LinkedListNode{
    public:
        T data;
        LinkedListNode *next;
        LinkedListNode();
};
```

---

In my LinkedList Class, I have private variables:

```
private:
    LinkedListNode *head;
    //iterator for traversing the list
    LinkedListNode *current;
```

};

When compiling, I am getting strange errors:

> ./LinkedList.h:38:3: error: unknown type name 'LinkedListNode'; did you mean
>         'LinkedList'?
>                   LinkedListNode *head;
>                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                   LinkedList
>   ./LinkedList.h:13:7: note: 'LinkedList' declared here
>   class LinkedList{
>         ^
>   ./LinkedList.h:40:3: error: unknown type name 'LinkedListNode'; did you mean
>         'LinkedList'?
>                   LinkedListNode *current;
>                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                   LinkedList
>   ./LinkedList.h:13:7: note: 'LinkedList' declared here
>   class LinkedList{
>         ^
>   LinkedList.cpp:7:1: error: 'LinkedListNode' is not a class, namespace, or
>         enumeration
>   LinkedListNode::LinkedListNode(){
>   ^
>   ./LinkedList.h:5:7: note: 'LinkedListNode' declared here
>   class LinkedListNode{
>         ^

Why am i getting these errors if it says my LinkedListNode is also being declared?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`LinkedListNode` is not a type, but `LinkedListNode<T>` is. Be sure to [implement `LinkedListNode::LinkedListNode()` and other member functions in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1), and `#include` this header file before the definition of `LinkedList<T>`.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    LinkedListNode<T> *head;
    LinkedListNode<T> *current;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, compiler is saying that you do not have the type `LinkedListNode`, and compiler is right - `LinkedListNode` is a template, not a type. To form a type, you need to instantiate the template with an argument. For example, `LinkedListNode<int>` is a type.

However, your compiler could provide a better diagnostic. For example, g++ would:

> 4 : error: missing template arguments before 'x'